# In what order are autotools invoked to create a build system?

Tags: c, autotools

I'm trying to use autotools to create a build system for a C program. However, after reading `info automake`, I'm still very confused about the order of which tools are invoked by the developer.

Let's think about a very simple hello world application. In the root dir of the application there is simple `src/hello.c` and nothing else. What tools need to be called in what order to create `configure` and a `Makefile`?

I figured out by myself (partially reading doc, partially just trying) that `autoscan` comes first and generates a "sketch" of the `configure.ac`. Then `autoheader` appearently creates a header file (why?). Next `autoconf` finally creates the `configure` script, which will ultimately create a `config.h`.

However, I am still missing a `Makefile` which I believe is created by `automake`, but this requires a `Makefile.am` which I don't know how to generate. Is this file generated at all or hand-written by the developer?

Comment: This doesn't really answer your question, but I've never found the autotools to be anything other than painful and confusing.  Other build systems are becoming increasingly common, like [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/).  They have their own problems, but generally accomplish the same thing as the autotools with a lot less confusion and hassle.  If you're not set on using autotools, you might want to look at some of the alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

The functionality of the autotools tends to blur at the edges. There's a decent flow chart describing the ordering [here](http://www.developingprogrammers.com/index.php/2006/01/05/autotools-tutorial/). The `Makefile.am` is typically hand-written. Many projects keep a simple shell script at the top-level of the source tree, i.e., `autogen.sh` or `initgen.sh`. The `autogen.sh` I use:

```
#! /bin/sh

case `uname` in Darwin*) glibtoolize --copy ;;
    *) libtoolize --copy ;; esac

aclocal -I m4 --install
autoheader
autoconf

automake --foreign --add-missing --force-missing --copy
```

[This](http://www.freesoftwaremagazine.com/books/autotools_a_guide_to_autoconf_automake_libtool) is still one of the best practical guides I've seen. I believe it's available in book form too.

Comment: You can also run `autoreconf` which is part of the autotools suite which is intended to run them in the right order, but it may not be correct for every project since it can't know specific directories or options.  See http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/autoreconf-Invocation.html

Answer (score 1):

Your Makefile.am should look something like

```
bin_PROGRAMS = hello
AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = foreign
hello_SOURCES = src/hello.c
```

Run automake and it will create a Makefile.in